# MYSQL SELECT PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

I got 2 tables and I want list the result of each day from salesman.

One table contain salesman info ( id,name)

The other contain the sales of the day (saleschipcell, cell)

After joining two tables, I got the result from each day:

```
salesman John, day -> 01/03/2012   cell -> 15, chip cell ->30

salesman Bob, day  -> 01/03/2012   cell -> 5, chip cell ->10

salesman John, day -> 01/04/2012   cell -> 10, chip cell ->0

salesman Bob, day  -> 01/04/2012   cell -> 10, chip cell ->2
```

Ok.Is there a possibility to get the total of sales from cell and chipcell from John and BOB like this:

```
Total of the day , day  -> 01/03/2012   cell -> 20, chip cell ->40

Total of the day , day  -> 01/04/2012   cell -> 20, chip cell ->2
```

I tried with `SUM`, but generates only one result, but SUM get all from all salesman.

Comment: That's what `GROUP BY` is for.

Comment: Can you please post the actual query you are using?  See also [GROUP BY](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can group the results per salesman to get the totals for that specific person. Example:

```
SELECT `day`, SUM(`saleschipcell`) FROM `sales` GROUP BY `salesman_id`;
```

Should give you the amount of sales per day per salesman.

Comment: Select promotor.id as promoid,  promotor.promotor as promonome,   produtosales.idpromotor as salespromo, prosutosales.datesales as datasell, produtosales.combos as salescombos from promotor INNER JOIN produtosales on promotor.id = produtosales.idpromotor where promotor.idpdv = '33' order by promotor.id,prosutosales.datesales asc

Comment: I want the total of the day from John and bob, I mean total chipsell and total cell, distinct per day

Comment: Use your query with `GROUP BY day`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `day`,SUM('cell'), SUM(`chipcell`) FROM `sales` GROUP BY `day`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it by day and by person use two columns in Group by

```
SELECT `day`,`salesman_id`,SUM('cell') as cell, SUM(`chipcell`) as chipcell 
FROM `sales` 
GROUP BY `day`, `salesman_id`
ORDER BY `day`
```